# How can I set the variable with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I wonder how I can set the variable `this.form.answer`, because it says that it's undefined but axios promise does returns a value...

```
axios
  .get("/api/rut/" + this.form.rut + "/edit?api_token=" + App.apiToken)
  .then((response) => {
    this.post = response.data;
    this.$set(this.form, "answer", this.post);
  });

var answer;
answer = this.form.answer;
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean set `answer` when `this.form.answer` is not defined until the ajax call has been resolved? Why do you need to set `answer`, when it gets set in the `then`?

Comment: If I add this inside then...I use this.answer lower but  and it keeps undefined data

Comment: `axios.get` is asynchronous. The lines after `axios.get` tries to read `this.form.answer` *before* `axios.get` has resolved (`this.form.answer` is not yet set).

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html):

Try adding the `this.$set...` inside a `this.$nextTick()` function.